# Keep AngularJS data inside content div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to keep angularjs data inside a div that is styled using css grid. Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/Rwbmmdy

The table spills over onto the header part of the grid. On a separate real world project the data spans the entire length of page spilling outside all the css div containers. How do I keep the data retrieved from angularjs inside the content div? Thank you.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myController',
        function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.list = [
  {
     "ID": "001",
     "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
     "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "002",
      "Name": "Bald Eagle",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "003",
      "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "004",
      "Name": "Bell's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "005",
      "Name": "Mourning Dove",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "006",
      "Name": "Rock Pigeon",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "007",
      "Name": "Abert's Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "008",
      "Name": "Brewer's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "009",
      "Name": "Canyon Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "010",
      "Name": "Black Vulture",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
    {
     "ID": "011",
     "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
     "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "012",
      "Name": "Bald Eagle",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "013",
      "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "014",
      "Name": "Bell's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "015",
      "Name": "Mourning Dove",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "016",
      "Name": "Rock Pigeon",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "017",
      "Name": "Abert's Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "018",
      "Name": "Brewer's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "019",
      "Name": "Canyon Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "020",
      "Name": "Black Vulture",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  }
  ];
      
  $scope.reverseOrder = true;
  $scope.sortField = 'ID';
    
  $scope.sortBy = function(sortField) {
  $scope.reverseOrder = ($scope.sortField === sortField) ? !$scope.reverseOrder : false;
      $scope.sortField = sortField;
  };
        
 });
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  color: #96ceb4;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexbox-header > div {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.header :nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.header :nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.grid-page > div {
    color: #ffeead;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.flexbox-header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #96ceb4;
  color: #ffeead;
}

.flexbox-header :nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px 70% 40px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #96ceb4;
  align-items: center;
}

.left-menu {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.content {
  grid-column: span 8;
  background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.right-menu {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #88d8b0;
}

table 
{
  width: auto;
  font: 17px Calibri;
}
table, th, td 
{
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="flexbox-header">
    <div>HOME</div>
    <div>SEARCH</div>
    <div>LOGOUT</div>
  </div>
  GRID PAGE
  <div class="grid-page">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="left-menu">MENU</div>
    <div class="content">
      <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
        <table id="searchTextResults">
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('ID')">ID</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Name')">Bird Name</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Type')">Type of Bird</th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="birds in list | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder">
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.ID}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Name}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Type}}</a></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="right-menu">CHARTS</div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change display on class `.grid-page > div`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myController',
        function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.list = [
  {
     "ID": "001",
     "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
     "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "002",
      "Name": "Bald Eagle",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "003",
      "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "004",
      "Name": "Bell's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "005",
      "Name": "Mourning Dove",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "006",
      "Name": "Rock Pigeon",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "007",
      "Name": "Abert's Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "008",
      "Name": "Brewer's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "009",
      "Name": "Canyon Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "010",
      "Name": "Black Vulture",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
    {
     "ID": "011",
     "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
     "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "012",
      "Name": "Bald Eagle",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "013",
      "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  },
  {
      "ID": "014",
      "Name": "Bell's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "015",
      "Name": "Mourning Dove",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "016",
      "Name": "Rock Pigeon",
      "Type": "Dove"
  },
  {
      "ID": "017",
      "Name": "Abert's Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "018",
      "Name": "Brewer's Sparrow",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "019",
      "Name": "Canyon Towhee",
      "Type": "Sparrow"
  },
  {
      "ID": "020",
      "Name": "Black Vulture",
      "Type": "Hawk"
  }
  ];
      
  $scope.reverseOrder = true;
  $scope.sortField = 'ID';
    
  $scope.sortBy = function(sortField) {
  $scope.reverseOrder = ($scope.sortField === sortField) ? !$scope.reverseOrder : false;
      $scope.sortField = sortField;
  };
        
 });
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  color: #96ceb4;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexbox-header > div {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.header :nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.header :nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.grid-page > div {
    color: #ffeead;
    display: block; // dont use flex
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.flexbox-header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #96ceb4;
  color: #ffeead;
}

.flexbox-header :nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 40px 70% 40px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #96ceb4;
  align-items: center;
}

.left-menu {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.content {
  grid-column: span 8;
  background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.right-menu {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #ff6f69;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #88d8b0;
}

table 
{
  width: auto;
  font: 17px Calibri;
}
table, th, td 
{
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="flexbox-header">
    <div>HOME</div>
    <div>SEARCH</div>
    <div>LOGOUT</div>
  </div>
  GRID PAGE
  <div class="grid-page">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="left-menu">MENU</div>
    <div class="content">
      <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
        <table id="searchTextResults">
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('ID')">ID</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Name')">Bird Name</th>
                <th ng-click="sortBy('Type')">Type of Bird</th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="birds in list | filter:searchText | orderBy:sortField:reverseOrder">
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.ID}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Name}}</a></td>
              <td><a href="#">{{birds.Type}}</a></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="right-menu">CHARTS</div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```